# UWP Grouped Listview with editable multiline textboxes performance

Tags: c#, performance, xaml, listview, uwp

I have this issue when trying to implement a Grouped ListView with editable multiline TextBoxes: When trying to type in the TextBox and change line (press enter or text requires to wrap) and the increased height of the typing TextBox causes the ListViewItem (the row) to increase, then the UI thread performance seems sluggish.

This UI performance snag is more obvious when there are quite a few groups with various number of items per group (from 0 to let's say 5) and each text has multiline content.

The issue disappears in the following cases:

1. ListView is not grouped
2. ListView virtualization is overridden (by using StackPanel instead of ItemsStackPanel as ItemsPanelTemplate), but I lose the loading performance benefits of virtualization and the Group header nice sticky behavior.

To populate the ListView I use model binding. Here is the code I use:

This is a dummy model to hold data for the editable TextBoxes and the collection object of MyModel to generate the group with a CollectionName property to show as group header.

```
public class MyModel
{
    public string Cell1 { get; set; }
    public string Cell2 { get; set; }
    public string Cell3 { get; set; }
}

public class MyModelCollection : Collection<MyModel>
{
    public string CollectionName { get; set; }
}
```

Then the ViewModel to fill data to display in the View: You can notice that I generate groups with 0 to 5 items (rows). Each row should consist of three multiline TextBoxes (cells).

```
public class MainPageViewModel
{
    public List<MyModelCollection> MyModelCollections { get; set; }
    public MainPageViewModel()
    {
        var myCollections = new List<MyModelCollection>();

        for (var j = 0; j < 20; j++)
        {
            var myCollection = new MyModelCollection();
            myCollection.CollectionName = "Title of group " + j;
            var iMax = 5;
            if (j == 0|| j == 5 || j == 6 || j == 9 || j == 11) iMax = 0;
            if (j == 3 || j == 7 || j == 8) iMax = 1;
            if (j == 2 || j == 10) iMax = 3;
            for (var i = 0; i < iMax; i++)
            {
                var row = new MyModel();

                var multiLine1 = new StringBuilder();
                multiLine1.AppendLine("Line1 Line1 Line1 Line1 Line1 Line1 Line1 Line1 Line1 Line1 Line1 Line1 Line1 Line1 Line1 Line1 Line1 Line1 Line1Line1Line1Line1 Line1 Line1 Line1 Line1 Line1 Line1 Line1 Line1 Line1 Line1 Line1 Line1 Line1 Line1 Line1 Line1 Line1 Line1 Line1 Line1 Line1 Line1 Line1 Line1 Line1 Line1 Line1 Line1 Line1 Line1 Line1 Line1 Line1 Line1 Line1 Line1 Line1 Line1 Line1 Line1 Line1 Line1 Line1 Line1 Line1 Line1 Line1 Line1 Line1 Line1 Line1 Line1 Line1 Line1 Line1 Line1 Line1 Line1 Line1 Line1 Line1 Line1 Line1 Line1 Line1 Line1 Line1 Line1 Line1 Line1 Line1 Line1 Line1 Line1 Line1 Line1 Line1 Line1 Line1 Line1 Line1 Line1 Line1 Line1 Line1 Line1 Line1 Line1 Line1 Line1 Line1 Line1 Line1 Line1 Line1 Line1 Line1 Line1 Line1 Line1 Line1 Line1 Line1 Line1 Line1 Line1 Line1 Line1 Line1 Line1 Line1 Line1 Line1 Line1 Line1 Line1 Line1 Line1 Line1 Line1 Line1 Line1 Line1 Line1 Line1 Line1 Line1 Line1 Line1 Line1 Line1 Line1 Line1 Line1 Line1 Line1 Line1 Line1 ");
                multiLine1.AppendLine("Line2 Line2 Line2 Line2 Line2 Line2 Line2 Line2 Line2 Line2 Line2 Line2 Line2 Line2 Line2 Line2 Line2Line2Line2 Line2 Line2Line2 Line2Line2 Line2 Line2 Line2 Line2 Line2 Line2Line2 Line2 Line2 Line2 Line2Line2 Line2 Line2 Line2 Line2");
                row.Cell1 = multiLine1.ToString();

                var multiLine2 = new StringBuilder();
                multiLine2.AppendLine("Line1");
                multiLine2.AppendLine("Line2Line2 Line2 Line2 Line2 Line2 Line2 Line2 Line2 Line2 Line2 Line2 Line2 Line2 Line2 Line2 Line2 Line2Line2Line2 Line2 Line2Line2 Line2Line2 Line2 Line2 Line2 Line2 Line2 Line2Line2 Line2 Line2 Line2 Line2Line2 Line2 Line2 Line2 Line2");
                multiLine2.AppendLine("Line3");
                multiLine2.AppendLine("Line4");
                row.Cell2 = multiLine2.ToString();

                var multiLine3 = new StringBuilder();
                multiLine3.AppendLine("Line1");
                multiLine3.AppendLine("Line2Line2 Line2 Line2 Line2 Line2 Line2 Line2 Line2 Line2 Line2 Line2 Line2 Line2 Line2 Line2 Line2 Line2Line2Line2 Line2 Line2Line2 Line2Line2 Line2 Line2 Line2 Line2 Line2 Line2Line2 Line2 Line2 Line2 Line2Line2 Line2 Line2 Line2 Line2");
                multiLine3.AppendLine("Line3 Line3 Line3 Line3Line3 Line3Line3 Line3Line3 Line3Line3 Line3Line3 Line3Line3 Line3Line3 Line3Line3 Line3Line3 Line3Line3 Line3");
                row.Cell3 = multiLine3.ToString();

                myCollection.Add(row);
            }

            myCollections.Add(myCollection);
        }


        MyModelCollections = myCollections;
    }
}
```

Then MainPageViewModel is set as DataContext of the XAML page (named as ViewModel)

```
<Page.DataContext>
    <local:MainPageViewModel x:Name="ViewModel"/>
</Page.DataContext>
```

Then the CollectionViewSource in XAML page resources to enable binding:

```
<Page.Resources>
    <CollectionViewSource x:Key="CollectionsSource" IsSourceGrouped="True" Source="{x:Bind ViewModel.MyModelCollections, Mode=OneWay}"></CollectionViewSource>
</Page.Resources>
```

And finally the ListView control in the XAML view

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource CollectionsSource}}">
    <ListView.GroupStyle>
        <GroupStyle HidesIfEmpty="False" >
            <GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:MyModelCollection">
                    <Grid>
                        <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind CollectionName}"/>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
        </GroupStyle>
    </ListView.GroupStyle>
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:MyModel">
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                <TextBox Text="{x:Bind Cell1, Mode=TwoWay}" TextWrapping="Wrap" BorderThickness="0" Grid.Column="0" AcceptsReturn="True"/>
                <TextBox Text="{x:Bind Cell2, Mode=TwoWay}" TextWrapping="Wrap" BorderThickness="0" Grid.Column="1" AcceptsReturn="True"/>
                <TextBox Text="{x:Bind Cell3, Mode=TwoWay}" TextWrapping="Wrap" BorderThickness="0" Grid.Column="2" AcceptsReturn="True"/>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

When trying to run the above code, if I scroll down to the last item of group 4 (the Groups 5,6 and 7 are shown below in the screen) and try to write in the first cell causing the item's height to increase, then the performance of the UI is poor. In some other typing cases, this performance snag is not that obvious, you can try...

As written earlier the performance issue disappears:

1. if I remove group items (ListViewHeaderItem) and the easiest way is to completely remove ListView.GroupStyle element from the ListView in XAML
2. or I remove ListView virtualization by using plain StackPanel as ItemsPanelTemplate (see the new ListView xaml below)

   ```
   <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource CollectionsSource}}">
       <ListView.GroupStyle>
           <GroupStyle HidesIfEmpty="False" >
               <GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                   <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:MyModelCollection">
                       <Grid >
                           <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind CollectionName}"/>
                       </Grid>
                   </DataTemplate>
               </GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
           </GroupStyle>
       </ListView.GroupStyle>
       <ListView.ItemsPanel>
           <ItemsPanelTemplate>
               <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical"/>
           </ItemsPanelTemplate>
       </ListView.ItemsPanel>
       <ListView.ItemTemplate>
           <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:MyModel">
               <Grid>
                   <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                       <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                       <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                       <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                   </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                   <TextBox Text="{x:Bind Cell1, Mode=TwoWay}" TextWrapping="Wrap" BorderThickness="0" Grid.Column="0" AcceptsReturn="True"/>
                   <TextBox Text="{x:Bind Cell2, Mode=TwoWay}" TextWrapping="Wrap" BorderThickness="0" Grid.Column="1" AcceptsReturn="True"/>
                   <TextBox Text="{x:Bind Cell3, Mode=TwoWay}" TextWrapping="Wrap" BorderThickness="0" Grid.Column="2" AcceptsReturn="True"/>
               </Grid>
           </DataTemplate>
       </ListView.ItemTemplate>
   </ListView>
   ```

Comment: How did you judge the performance of the UI is poor?

Comment: @XavierXie-MSFT, in my environment the performance drop is visually obvious and also there is a drastic increase in the CPU usage in Visual Studio diagnostics while debuging. Simply hitting ENTER to add lines in the textboxes freezes the UI for some time, when the ListViewItem height is updated. The behavior change with the two alternative suggestions that disappear the performance issue is realy obvious.